# how to make this image as large as possible on the page

Tags: floats, center

[image]I would like to make the image legible (without glasses) and therefore I would like it bigger! how can I do?

```
\section{Quali lavori si possono fare a casa?}

La figura \ref{fig:codIsco}  mostra i valori della telelavoro tecnico e degli indici di interazione sociale per alcuni dei 121 gruppi di occupazione a 3 cifre ISCO.
\begin{figure}[H] % Qui (here), se possibile
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=16cm,height=14cm, angle=90 ]{img/TeleInt.png}
\caption[Valori della telelavoro tecnico e degli indici di interazione sociale per alcuni dei 121 codici ISCO]{\small{Valori della telelavoro tecnico e degli indici di interazione sociale per alcuni dei 121 codici ISCO}}
\label{fig:codIsco}
\end{center}
\end{figure}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Unrelated: never use `center` to center inside a float, `center` adds vertical spacing, as does `figure`, so here you have double vertical space. Replace `\begin{center} ` by `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`.  I would also recommend that you never use `[H]` and instead use something like `[htp]` and refer to the image via the label (as you already do).

Comment: I'd suggest using `angle=90,width=\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight,keepaspectratio`. By rotating first then the sizes you give are after the rotation. `0.9...` leaves a bit of space for the caption

Comment: a graphic with letters that are upside down is never legible. Imho you should remake this, e.g. with tikz.